# Terminal velocity of (slightly heavier-than-air) falling balloon

Tags: buoyancy, fluid-statics, viscosity

My sense from general experience, not formal experiment, is that larger-radius balloons fall slower. But I'm not getting that answer, as follows.

The downward force is just proportional to $r^3$ (ignoring $r$-dependencies of balloon membrane weight and internal pressure), so $f_d\sim r^3$. And the upward drag/air_resistance is typically proportional to $v^2$ and the cross-sectional surface area, so $f_u\sim\alpha r^2v^2$, just gathering all constants into that $\alpha$. But then $f_d=f_u$ for terminal velocity gives $v^2=r/\alpha$, whereby bigger balloons fall faster, opposite my expectation.

What I want to do is determine $\alpha$ by assuming a given $v_0$ for a particular $r_0$, whereby $\alpha=r_0/v_0^2$, and then just semi-realistically scale $v$ for different $r$'s using that given $\alpha$. So is the preceding the right way to do it? Seems simple enough, but like I said initially, my sense is that bigger balloons should fall slower.

( P.S. Don't laugh (too much:), but this question is inspired by the NexGard tv commercial, e.g., http://dogsoncamera.com/nexgard-2017-tv-commercial/ which I want to add as an effect on my http://www.forkosh.com/gifscroll.html )

**Edit** in reply to @ScienceAsap's comment below. Here's an example of the balloons as currently programmed in that http://www.forkosh.com/gifscroll.html program cited above (see the webpage for instructions about how to create similar images)...

[image]

Hmm...for some reason I'm not seeing the imgur gif displayed by the <img> tag directly above. The imgur link to it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFcAG.jpg   ( But a better-displaying version is at http://www.forkosh.com/images/noregerts3.gif  )

Comment: It might be a bad idea to ignore the weight of the membrane, as it dwarfs the weight of the air inside.

Comment: Which fall slower - normal rain water droplets or the much smaller water droplets which we call mist?

Comment: @probably_someone Two things: (1) actually not -- I went to the local PathMark that always has large helium-filled balloons on display and on sale (God knows why). Tug on one, and the weight of air minus weight of helium is really quite unexpectedly large. Obviously not larger than you'd calculate, but way larger than you'd intuitively guess. And (2), this would just make the larger balloon fall even faster, and I'm thinking it should be slower. Of course, I'm likely thinking wrong. But either way, while membrane weight isn't trivial, I don't think it's overly significant, either.

Comment: Wait, the balloons are filled with helium? I was assuming they were filled with air. You should specify that in the question.

Comment: @Farcher Okay, you're certainly intuitively right about that, without any calculation. But my qualitative balloon intuition is still larger $\sim$ slower (though I could certainly be quantitatively wrong). Could mist be affected by Brownian motion, or some other effect that scales in such a way as to reverse the result at larger sizes?

Comment: @probably_someone No, you're right -- the NexGard video has falling balloons, presumably air-filled. The point of the helium demo is that you can feel how the air inside a balloon is way heavier than you might expect, just by tugging.

Comment: Right, but you can't ignore bouyant forces here while accounting for them in the case of helium. Accounting for bouyant forces (and assuming equal density inside and outside the balloon), the air inside the balloon weighs nothing.

Comment: @probably_someone Hmm...yeah, I'm thinking you're right. But don't you have pretty much the same larger-balloon intuition? Let go of two air-filled balloons, and the larger one floats around longer. But I'm now thinking the explanation might just be that ambient room air isn't typically stationary, but there are always small currents. And the larger ballooon will be affected more (as per usual $r^2$ stuff). And that's why it floats longer. Nothing to do with terminal velocity. Of course, in that case, my underlying "how to do a realistic simulation" question needs a whole different approach.

Comment: I just tried it with two balloon. Heavy balloon is slower and smaller balloon lands first.

Comment: @ScienceAsap Thanks for definitive physical answer. But it's really more of a "decorative effect" for animated gifs. I completed the programming a while back. And see post above, where I've edited in an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- All balloons are filled with air
- The rubber membrane on each is the same thickness and is stretched to the same tension

We have from the first assumption that the only downward force is the force of gravity on the rubber membrane. In turn, since all membranes are the same thickness, the weight of the balloon is proportional to the area of the rubber used (i.e. the surface area of the balloon), which is proportional to $r^2$. Since balloons are roughly spherical, we can also assume that their cross-sectional area is proportional to $r^2$. These factors of $r^2$ cancel out when equating gravity with drag, so **the terminal velocity is independent of balloon size, given the above assumptions.**

You might want to re-check your personal experience, just to be sure (as I don't really remember the last time I dropped two differently-sized air-filled balloons). If you do end up getting something different, it's likely because of one of two things:

- the membrane on one balloon was thicker than the other, or
- one balloon was inflated to higher tension, meaning that for the same weight of rubber, more drag was experienced.

This generally fits with your personal experience that bigger balloons fall slower, as in most common situations, you'll be comparing two balloons of identical deflated size, which you've inflated to different sizes (and thus different tensions).

Comment: Thanks again (in addition to preceding comments). Yeah, I guess you were right all along: air_inside=air_outside, and membrane's the determining factor. Speed (#pixels/frame) will just require a few lines of code, so I'll see how it aesthetically looks with (more or less correct) constant speed versus some-small-r-dependence to be determined.